# Spreadsheet function does not run when button clicked

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I previously asked a [two-part question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863795/trouble-with-time-stamp-script-activated-on-button-press-for-google-sheets), and only one part was answered and then closed, while the other part was left unanswered. I'm re-asking that part.

I'm in charge of creating an "automatic" project tracking sheet for my team. Automatic in the sense that someone presses a button, it logs a date/time stamp, and the time they spent on said project is automatically calculated for them.

However, when I connect a script to a Google Drawing to act as a button, it doesn't do anything, and I am unable to figure out why.

Here is what my spreadsheet looks like, with a button (drawing) configured to run the `timeStamp()` function when clicked:

[image: screenshot]

You can also get a copy of the spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gMX6w__p16apiSOjnwYWK8bYPRLqosvQpCUZ3aLSDzs/edit?usp=sharing).

The code I've got so far:

```js
function timeStamp() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var timezone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone;
  var timeFormat = "hh:mm a";

  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastCell = sheet.getRange(lastRow, lastCol);
  var timeStampCell = sheet.getRange(lastRow, lastCol + 1);


  if(timeStampCell === " ") {
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timeFormat); 
    timeStampCell.setValue(date);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var timeStampCell = sheet.getRange(lastRow, lastCol + 1);
```

...sets `timeStampCell` to a Range object.

```
if(timeStampCell === " ") {
```

...compares that Range object to a String containing a single space character. The comparison is always `false`, because the types are different. If `==` was used for the comparison with type coercion allowed, it would still evaluate `false` because the operands are just different.

You probably want the cell's contents, and to compare them to an empty string:

```
if(timeStampCell.getValue() === "")
```

Note: take care using `===` with the contents of Spreadsheet cells. If the comparison is for Date objects, `===` will evaluate `true` only when both operands are the exact same *object*. See [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)

In this example, you don't really care what data type comes from the spreadsheet, only that it is blank. Therefore, you could use `==`.

```
if(timeStampCell.getValue() == "")
```

Another problem, here:

```
var timezone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone;
```

This will get a reference to the Spreadsheet "getSpreadsheetTimeZone" method, but it will *not* tell you the timezone. To get the result of the method, you need to call it by including parentheses:

```
var timezone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
```

With those two changes, the script works for me.

Comment: Thank you! Several things I didn't notice. The button finally does something! Seems that it doesn't put data where I want it to, but I think I finally know how to get it up and running.